# How to make two tabs take whole screen width in angular material 2

Tags: html, angular, css, angular-material2

I am using angular material 2 and  have only two tabs  and want them to take up the whole screen width (half each, see pic2). How can I do that (by default it looks like pic1)?

```
pic1
------------------------------------------------
| ITEM1 | ITEM 2 |
------------------------------------------------

pic 2
------------------------------------------------
|         ITEM1        |          ITEM 2       |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Angular Material uses Flex, but it's not integrated in their github, so you have to install it from [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). Otherwise you can get away with [grid-list](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview), or bootstrap's column approach

Comment: Can you  provide with a snippet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `[mat-stretch-tabs]` property:

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Tab 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Tab 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Note: For some reason, it only works on the `mat-tab-group` component, but not `nav[mat-tab-nav-bar]`.

Comment: This should be in the API

Comment: @emvidi It's actually a CSS class but I still agree with you.

Comment: @Edric Is there separate documentation for CSS properties?

Comment: @garg10may AFAIK, there's no docs for these properties. It's probably specified in the docs for the tab component though.

Comment: @Edric no it's nowhere in material docs, for what I am trying to understand is, how you even got to know that there's something called as "mat-stretch-tabs"

Comment: @garg10may There's actually an example in the Angular Material docs: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples (If you scroll down to the example titled "Tab group with stretched labels")

Answer (score 1):

The labels can be targeted using the CSS class `mat-tab-label`.

try the following CSS:

```
.mat-tab-label {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Also, you can use mat-stretch-tabs property:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
    <mat-tab label="ITEM 1">ITEM1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="ITEM 2">ITEM2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```